# what should i do for get all http links in cURL

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I created a program in php using CURL, in which i can take data of any site and can display it in the browser. Another part of the program is that the data can be saved in the file using file handling and after saving this data, I can find all the http links within the body tag of the saved file. My code is showing all the sites in the browser which I took, **but I can not find all http links**

Kindly help me out this problem.

PHP Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display links using Curl</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $GetData = curl_init();
            $url = "http://www.ucertify.com/";
            curl_setopt($GetData, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($GetData, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($GetData);
            curl_close($GetData);
            $file=fopen("content.txt","w");
            fputs($file,$data);
            fclose($file);
            echo $data;
            function links() {
                $file_content = file_get_contents("http://www.ucertify.com/");
                $dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
                @$dom_obj->loadHTML($file_content);
                $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_obj);
                $links_href = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
                for ($i = 0; $i<$links_href->length; $i++) {
                    $href = $links_href->item($i);
                    $url = $href->getAttribute("href");
                    if(strstr($url,"#")||strstr($url,"javascript:void(0)")||$url=="javascript:;"||$url=="javascript:"){}
                    else {
                        echo "<div>".$url."<div/>";
                    }
                }
            }
            echo links();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give examples of links that it should be finding but isn't?

Comment: Some content in web pages is assembled on-the-fly in browser via AJAX calls or iframes and this will not show up in HTML document accessed by cURL.

Comment: @Barmar This code only find those http links which came under href

Comment: @alo What other kinds of links are there?

Comment: there are more links under src or blank

Comment: i think we can use regex to find all links

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this

```
preg_match("/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $file_data, $body_content);
preg_match_all("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$body_content[1],$matches);
 foreach($matches[0] as $d) {
    echo $d."<br>";
    }
```